# Что не так с регулярным выражением?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

На сайте regex 101 я написал такое регулярное выражение:

`^(\(|)*(\(|)*(\!|)[A-Z](\)|)*((v|\^)(\!|)(\(|)*[A-Z](\)|)*)*(v|\^)(\!|)[A-Z](\)|)*$`

и там все отлично, оно валидирует мою строку как надо.

вот моя строка:

`D^!AvB^!(A^Bv(Av!C))v!CvB`

но проблема в том, что когда я вставляю регулярку в Qt Creator, то такая же строка не проходит валидацию. а метод `isValid()` возвращает `true`.

Ну и кусок кода из Qt:

```
QRegExp regExp("^(\(|)*(\(|)*(\!|)[A-Z](\)|)*((v|\^)(\!|)(\(|)*[A-Z](\)|)*)*(v|\^)(\!|)[A-Z](\)|)*$");
if (regExp.isValid()){
    cout << "is valid" << endl; 
} else {
    cout << regExp.errorString().toStdString() << endl;
}
cout << regExp.indexIn("D^!AvB^!(A^Bv(Av!C))v!CvB") << endl; // -1
```

Возможно в c++ нельзя писать так, как я написал, но я не знаю, так как на с++ не пишу. Исправте меня, где я ошибся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я давно не пишу на C++, но, судя по всему, здесь экранирование съедается строковым литералом. Стоит попробовать вместо "\" писать "\\", чтобы этого не происходило.

Вполне возможно, что есть и другие проблемы. Регулярные выражения не везде работают одинаково, в разных языках есть небольшие отличия.

Comment: Спасибо) "\\" помогло)

Comment: Ещё можно поставить R перед литералом и скобки вокруг вашей регулярки (R"(...)"), тогда не придется экранировать каждый бекслеш. (С++11).